# How to Slice A List by Passing A List or A Tuple Returned By A Function in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have lambda functions as below:

```
e_by_p = 20
prange_py = lambda x: (e_by_p*x-e_by_p, e_by_p*x)
```

So the outputs as below:

```
prange_py(1)
# (0, 20)
prange_py(2)
# (20,40)
prange_py(3)
# (40, 60)
# goes like that
```

So I want a list to be sliced with the values this function returns. For instance, assuming I have a list as below:

```
numbers = list(range(100,200))
# This is a default way to slice
numbers[0:20]
# [100, ..., 119]
# Using my function, passing <x> arg as 1
numbers[prange(1)[0]:prange(1)[1]]
```

However, this is not what I want to do. This is (i) too ugly, (ii) executing the same function twice. So I wonder if there is a way to *pass* a function's return which is tuple or list as a slice argument to a list.

Comment: Extract `prange(1)` as a variable before the slice? Then you only call it once and it isn't ugly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a slice object using [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) and pass in the function result as arguments:

```
numbers[slice(*prange_py(1))]
```

The `*` unpacks the tuple that `prange_py()` returns and passes it as arguments to the `slice()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Construct a slice object explicitly instead of using the `:` syntax.

```
numbers[slice(*prange_py(1))]
```

The tuple returned by `prange_py` is unpacked to pass two arguments to `slice`. `slice(a,b)` creates an object that can be used as an "index" equivalent to `numbers[a:b]`.

Comment: I accept this as valid answer since it is answered before the others. :) However, I have to wait for 8 mins. :(

Comment: Accept @poke's answer. Ours are otherwise identical and I think simultaneous, but he included a link to the `slice` documentation :)

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right this way. But let me think... :/

Answer (score 2):

`Lst[output[0]:output[1]]`

Where `lst` is the sliced And output is the tuple

Comment: Looking at others' answers, that might be better. Didn't know about slice objects. However my code might ve a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this method is very readable.

```
>>> a, b = prange_py(1);numbers[a:b]
[100,
 101,
 102,
 103,
 104,
 105,
 106,
 107,
 108,
 109,
 110,
 111,
 112,
 113,
 114,
 115,
 116,
 117,
 118,
 119]
```

Comment: Wow, late but this way seems quite interesting and readable. 0_0 | However, I will use a method here in very unreadable context in Django, seems like this: `entries_sorted = api_models.Entry.object.sort_by("-update_timedate").values_list("label", "value")[slice(*prange_py(page))]`. So it does not suit for me, but It will surely be okay for anyone else. :)